# How to print each gridview in a separate page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 3 grid views in my page. I'm using javascript to print all of them.

Now I want to Print each gridview in a separate page.

Below is my JavaScript Code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function PrintPanel() {
  var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
  var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');

  printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
  printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
  printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  printWindow.document.close();

  setTimeout(function () {
    printWindow.print();
  }, 500);

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use CSS to do this for me:
css:

```
.pageBreak {
    position: relative;
    page-break-after: always
 }
```

html:

```
<div id="gridView1" class="pageBreak">
   <!-- your grid view -->
</div>
```

in your case it might be something like:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function PrintPanel() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write('<div class="pagereak"'); 
    printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

though in your case the pageBreak class shoul;d be in the innerHTML I guess